# iOS .pch file fetch a error: "Invalid preprocessing directive"

Tags: ios

my .pch file :

```
 #ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #improt "Constant.h" // here there is a error: 
 #endif
```

line : #improt "Constant.h" fetch a error

```
Invalid preprocessing directive
```

what is the matter?

Answer (score 10):

Use "`#import`" and not "`#improt`" and you should be okay.

"Invalid preprocessing directive" is just another fancy way of saying "syntax" (or spelling) error.